# Python Search from the list based upon number of characters that match in element and print

Tags: python, search

I have list of cities that have numereous number of places names.
I want to make search from the list based upon number of characters that match in element and print
all  the elements that have matching number of those characters.

```
character_search = str(input("What character you are looking for: Choose from a-z? "))
number_of_characters = int(input("How many of those characters you are looking for in the name of the city? "))
```

#I have thise two inputs. Single character from a-z and how many of those you want to find from citys name.
#How can i make search from the list based upon thise two inputs and print all matches?

For example: If i choose character "o" and number three(3), it should find city called "porvoo", because it has three "o"'s in it and print it.
Also if I choose the character "a" and number three (3) it should find "tampabay" and "Aaria" and print both.

```
cities = ["Porvoo", "Tampabay", "Aaria"]
```

How do I do this?

Please help.

Comment: Please update the question to show what you’ve tried/researched so far.

Answer (score 0):

Use `count` and a loop to output all elements containing the requested amount of chars.

`count` will return the number of times the provided input occurs in the string. We just need to check that it matches the character count input.

```
result = [x for x in cities if x.lower().count(character_search.lower()) == number_of_characters]
```

Output with `a` * `3`

```
['Tampabay', 'Aaria']
```

Assumption is made that this should be insensitive to capitalization.